# Why is this struct type "incomplete," and is it really solved with a pointer?

Tags: c, gcc, data-structures, struct

I have defined these structures.

```
struct http_req {
    struct http_req_line rl;
}

struct http_req_line {
    enum method {
        OPTIONS,
        GET,
        HEAD,
        POST,
        PUT,
        DELETE,
        TRACE,
        CONNECT
    } method;
    enum uri_type {
        ASTERISK,
        ABSOLUTEURI,
        ABS_PATH,
        AUTHORITY
    } uri_type;
    union req_uri {
        char asterisk[1];
        char absoluteURI[256];
        char abs_path[256];
        char authority[256];
    } req_uri;
    char http_ver[16];
};
```

When I compile the file this header file is included in (which compiles fine on its own), gcc gives me this

```
request_types.h:2:23: error: field ‘rl’ has incomplete type
  struct http_req_line rl;
```

But changing the 2nd line of the header to

```
struct http_req_line *rl;
```

gets rid of this error. What causes this error, and does changing that member to a pointer really fix the problem, or just hide it from the compiler?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you try do declare the structure **before** using it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the point where the compiler sees:

```
struct http_req {
    struct http_req_line rl;
}
```

there is no information about what a `struct http_req_line` is.  You need the structure definition for `struct http_req` to appear after the definition of `struct http_req_line`.  You can use a pointer (to an incomplete type); you can't use a copy of the structure.

See the C11 standard [§6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1):

> A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type (hence, a structure shall not contain an instance of itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance of itself), …

Answer (score 4):

At the point where you are defining `struct http_req`, `struct http_req_line` is not known. The compiler does not know how big it is or what its alignment requirement is, so it does not know how much space to use for the `rl` member and cannot complete its definition of `struct http_req`.

If you want to embed a `struct http_req_line` inside a `struct http_req`, move the definition of `struct http_req_line` before the definition of `struct http_req`.

If you change `rl` to be a pointer, the type is not incomplete in the C sense because the compiler will know how big the pointer is and what its alignment requirement is. It does not need to know how big the structure it points to is in order to be able to plan space for the pointer `rl`.

Answer (score 4):

You're seeing this error because you're attempting to define an instance of a struct before the struct itself has been defined.  You need to define it first, then use it:

```
struct http_req_line {
    enum method {
        OPTIONS,
        GET,
        HEAD,
        POST,
        PUT,
        DELETE,
        TRACE,
        CONNECT
    } method;
    enum uri_type {
        ASTERISK,
        ABSOLUTEURI,
        ABS_PATH,
        AUTHORITY
    } uri_type;
    union req_uri {
        char asterisk[1];
        char absoluteURI[256];
        char abs_path[256];
        char authority[256];
    } req_uri;
    char http_ver[16];
};


struct http_req {
    struct http_req_line rl;
};
```

The reason that changing the member type to a pointer works is because you don't need to have the full struct definition to use a pointer to it.  When the type definition *is* needed is when that pointer would be dereferenced.